# how to resolve spring security context holder result null?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to spring MVC bellow is my spring-security.xml when i am retrieving the user details from security context holder its giving null.Please help me how can i resolve this problem.?

```
 <http auto-config="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*"
                       access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*"
                       access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/employee/*" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/campaign/*" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/marketing/*" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/company*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_EMPLOYEE"/>
        <intercept-url pattern=" /j_ascend_security_check*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_EMPLOYEE"/>

        <form-login login-page="/pages/login.jsp"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirectHandler"
                    authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureRedirectHandler"/>
    </http>
```

Java code

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
System.out.println("user at sh:::"+user.getCompanyShortName()); //getting null here
```

what is the problem.Can any one helpme out??

Comment: "getting null": is `user` or  `user.getCompanyShortName()` null?

Comment: security context holder giving the anonymusUser and when this will cast to User it is going to be null.user getting null @ kryger